# Material Design Theme Android Example

Tags: android, themes, material-design

I've used the following code.
http://www.incredibleandros.com/material-design-theme-android-example/

I like the example I performed all the steps.
But it did not work for me.
The colorPrimaryDark does not work.
The colorPrimaryDark does not change.
Is there anything else you need?
Android version  is 5.1
min sdk 
 compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {

```
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 8
    versionName "3.5"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTheme">@style/actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

</style>

<style name="actionbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#77cce6</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">

</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar">

</style>

<style name="NavigationViewStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <!-- menu item text size-->
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item>
    <!-- menu item height-->
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="NewDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

stylev21.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTheme">@style/actionbar</item>

</style>
```

[Screenshot pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG3mm.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are running not `Android > 5.0`. Try it at least in emulator.
You can't ever achive StatusBar colored without post Lollipop device.

Comment: @AlenSmith your system bar will only change if you have at least Android 5 (API 21) on your phone.

Comment: But in my phone Android version is 4.4.2 and in my app  info is  compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

Comment: One more time: your phone Android version is too old.

Comment: I running in Android version 5.1

Comment: @AlenSmith you accepted this answer half year ago and now you come back and say its not correct answer? Are you alright?

Comment: OK half year ago I think there is problem in my phone but when change phone and buy another version Android the new phone like Previous,so It's not my phone.in my phone there is some app that can change navigationBarColor but my cods can not change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Is there a code line in style.xml(v21)

<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigation_bar</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

For non Gradle user

instead of this..

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"
/>
```

to this..

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
        />
```